# report builder like salesforce has for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, reporting

Salesforce report builder is pretty awesome - see here http://www.salesforce.com/_app/video/chatter/help/report_builder.jsp.

Lots of my customers want similar functionality built into ruby on rails apps. I cant seem to find any good tool, framework or gem out there to do this sort of thing. Before I start building one myself, I wanted to see if anyone knew of something out there that was similar or could be used for the same purpose.